# Subspace of vector space represented as direct product

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Suppose that we are considering the space $V=\mathbb{F}_2^m\times \mathbb{F}_2^m$. If $W$ is an $m$-dimensional space, then $W$ can be either one of $0\times \mathbb{F}_2^m,\ \mathbb{F}_2^m\times 0$ or $W_1\times W_2$, where $W_1,W_2$ are subspaces of $\mathbb{F}_2^m$ such that $\dim(W_1)+\dim(W_2)=m$.

Is this correct? More precisely, if $W$ is a subspace of $V$ then it has to be of the form $W_1\times W_2$, right?

Comment: Not necessarily. Perhaps consider a slightly easier to visualise setting: $\Bbb{R} \times \Bbb{R}$, i.e. $\Bbb{R}^2$. Think about what $W_1 \times W_2$ could be in the plane $\Bbb{R}^2$ (hint: $W_1$ and $W_2$ have two possibilities: $\{0\}$ and $\Bbb{R}$). Try to think of other subspaces (e.g. lines through the origin) which don't match the four possibilities of $W_1 \times W_2$.

Comment: But what about this case, if the space is explicitely $\mathbb{F}_2^m\times \mathbb{F}_2^m$.

Comment: It has the same downside. Just as the line $y = x$ in $\Bbb{R}^2$ is a subspace not of this form, so too is the diagonal set $\{(x, x) : x \in \Bbb{F}^m_2\}$ a subspace not of this form. You could replace $(x, x)$ with $(x, \alpha x)$, where $\alpha \in \Bbb{F}^m_2 \setminus \{0\}$ too.